# Setting a Property On Runtime error - Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state

Tags: c#, object, properties

Say if I have a collection of objects called MyObjects.

Now I am looping on the above collection and adding it to another object called MyObject2. MyObjects has a property called 'files'.

I want to manipulate the value of files property when I am looping around my first collection. first of all can I do as code shown below. If yes, I get an error as follow :

```
{Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.} 

List<objects> MyObjects = Populate(); 
List<objects> MyObject2 = new List<objects>();
foreach(var item in MyObjects)
{
   item.files = "test file" + item.files;
   MyObject2.add(item);
}
```

edit ::

files property:

```
 [Transient]
        protected string _files;
        public string files
        {
            get
            {
               return _files;
            }
            set
            {
                _files= value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This error would appear to be unrelated, or there is not enough information provided to diagnose. Post all relevant code please.

Comment: but the error happens when i include item.files = "test file" + item.files; line of code...

Comment: First you can't expect us to guess where the error is occuring. Provide as much information in your question as possible. Second how do you expect us to know what type `objects.files` is or it's behavior without any context or code?

Comment: The only thing is that I am using Tereik ORM and that files property has transient attribute

Comment: Please show the code for the `files` property.

Comment: I'd guess `item.files` is a property whose setter is calling itself e.g. `set { this.files = value; }`

Comment: @Lee: Yup, that's my guess too.

Comment: @Sam1: That isn't the *actual* code, as that's a `Files` property, whereas your other code refers to the `files` property. It's vital that you post the *exact code* which is failing, not "code which is a bit like it, but retyped, possibly with vital changes".

Comment: @Sam1 The properties code does not match the first example.

Comment: @lee and JonSkeet that is right. isnt it right way to declare it?

Comment: @Sam1: No, the code you've edited it to would work... but the fact that initially you'd got the casing of the name wrong makes me nervous of whether you've *actually* copied and pasted, or just retyped it. The code as posted would be fine - without the uses of the underscores (in the property get/set) it would break.

Comment: @JonSkeet yea sorry i pasted the property but wrote the loop code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Psychic debugging - I suspect your `files` property looks something like this:

```
public string files
{
    get { return files; }
    set { files = value; }
}
```

That will just recurse forever until the stack blows up. That's just guesswork though, as you haven't shown us the crucial piece of code.

Comment: but originally it contains only around 9 characters and i want to append text to it and get this error

Comment: @Sam1 No, the code you posted uses a private backing variable.

Comment: so you mean if I use automatically implemented property I should be able but with long type of property i cannot? if so what difference does it make?

Comment: @Sam1 Is the posted `files` property code correct or not? I feel we are chasing a red herring here, and with your refusal to do anything to help debug the issue I don't see the question going much further.

Comment: @Sam1: No, you should be able to get it to work with a private backing variable - but you've got to make sure that you *really* use the backing variable, instead of recursing.

Comment: cool. thanks for now I have used another boolean property to do what I needed

Comment: @Sam1: You should *absolutely* work out exactly what was going wrong. Either your code is broken, or it isn't. We can't tell at the moment.